# How to add a new property to vue (object) data?

Tags: laravel, object, vue.js

I get the following error when using pagination in vue.js

> vue.js:2192 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.categories.push is not a function
>       at VueComponent.getAllChildren (vue.js:2192)
>       at vue.js:2207

script:

```
export default {
    name: "DisplayCategories",
    data() {
        return {
            categories: {},
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.categoriesList();
    },
    methods: {
        getAllChildren(currentValue, level) {

            for (let i = 0; i < currentValue.length; i++) {
                let current = currentValue[i];
                this.categories.push({
                    id: current.id,
                    name: Array(level + 1).join("....") + " " + current.name
                })
                if (current.children_recursive && current.children_recursive.length > 0) {
                    this.getAllChildren(current.children_recursive, level + 1)
                }
            }
        },
        categoriesList() {
            let uri = '/api/categories';
            this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
                this.getAllChildren(response.data.data, 0)
            });
        },
        getResults(page = 1) {
            axios.get('/api/categories?page=' + page)
                .then(response => {
                    this.categories = response.data;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('childrenRecursive')
        ->where('parent_id', null)
        ->paginate(5);

    return response()->json($categories, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `categories` as Object, and `.push()` method can be used only for Arrays. 
Define `categories` as Array:

```
    export default {
            name: "DisplayCategories",
            data(){
                return{
                    categories:[],

                }
            }, 
...
```

Comment: By turning it into an object, pagination doesn't work

Comment: Can the array be transformed into an object?